# Show null and not num values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query

```
with with_user_earns as (
            -- get father information (start)
            select father.id, father.str_name, father.id_father, father.ind_father_side_type, 1 as int_user_level from tb_user father where id = @v_user_id

            union all

            -- get son information (stop condition)
            select son.id, son.str_name, son.id_father, son.ind_father_side_type, WUE.int_user_level + 1 
            from tb_user as son inner join with_user_earns as WUE on son.id_father = WUE.id 
            where son.id_father is not null and WUE.int_user_level < @v_max_level
        )

        select aux.* 
        from (

            -- show result
            select with_user_earns.id id_son, with_user_earns.str_name str_son_name, with_user_earns.id_father, father.str_name str_father_name, with_user_earns.ind_father_side_type, with_user_earns.int_user_level, isnull(sum(o.int_score), 0) as int_score
            from with_user_earns inner join tb_order o on o.id_user = with_user_earns.id
                                 inner join tb_user as father on father.id = with_user_earns.id_father                   
            where o.dt_insert between @v_cycle_begin and @v_cycle_end and o.ind_payment_status = 3
            group by with_user_earns.id, with_user_earns.str_name, with_user_earns.id_father, with_user_earns.ind_father_side_type, with_user_earns.int_user_level, father.str_name

        ) as aux
        order by aux.int_user_level, aux.id_son
```

The table with_user_earns contains a lot of users (mult nivel hierarchy). 
Then I want to join with tb_order to get int_score 0 if the user sell nothing and if the user sell anything I want the sum of it.

I tried put left join, full outer join, ... But no one works perfect

What a need to do?

```
My result:
id_son int_score
1   100
2   11100
3   100
10  300

Expected result:
id_son int_score
1   100
2   11100
3   100
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
9   0
10  300
```

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Put the input data and expected output.

Comment: My result just show Users that sold anything. It happened because I filtered by date and status type (paid).

Comment: Without data your query and your problem not makes any sense. Put some data in question.

Comment: Can you understand now? The 'with_user_earns' table return all 10 users, but when I filter by date I lost them

Comment: Select `DISTINCT` id_son values from your current table and do a `LEFT JOIN` with your aggregation.